# dealing with missing properties on nested object while destructring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to destructure a nested object. what is the best way to avoid exceptions when some of the nested properties are missing, while assigning those who do exist?

```
const data = {
  title: 'hello',
  // nest: {
  //   road: 5
  // }
};

const { title, nest: { road = '' } } = data;

console.log(road);
/** i want it to return '' or undefined. 
 *  actually it returns: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'
 * 
*/
console.log(title)
/** i want it to return 'hello'
 * actually: never got there as there was an exception.
 */
```

Comment: Know your `Object` types that you want to deconstruct. That is what Javascript's type system is telling you. Anyway, if there is no `road` property, just provide an empty parent object `nest: {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign in a parent object level to empty object (or with value) even if it has further nested object destruction:

```js
const { title, nest: { road = '<default road>' } = {} } = data;
```

```js
const data = {
  title: 'hello',
   //nest: {
   //  road: 5
   //}
};

const { title, nest: { road = '<default road>' } = {} } = data;

console.log(title);
console.log(road);
```

And also, you are doing it wrong, if you are destructing using

```js
{title: englishTitle} = {title: 1234}
```

then, you should use `englishTitle` to get the value `1234`, and not **title**, or use

```js
{title} = {title: 1234}
```

and use `title` to get `1234`

Comment: learned something new! Didn't realize you could assign default values to destructured objects!

Comment: edited my question , removed the englishTitle as it was wrong

Comment: Hmm, thats ok, but I ope its addressed your actual problem:)

Comment: it did addressed (: